# How to keep long hair from getting everywhere?

Tags: cleaning, personal-care

I live with someone who has long hair. It seems to get everywhere. Even 24-48 hours after cleaning I can find it on floors, on tables, on furniture. Is there anything they or I can do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You don't need a lifehack. What you need, is to tell the person you live with to clean his own mess.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing, except ask the person you live with to keep their hair tied up all the time when indoors, either in a pony tail or pinned up. You will still get some hair about the place when they loosen it, unless you expect the person to tie it up before they come in the door and not loosen it till they leave again. Which isn't a particularly reasonable request, I'd have thought, if they live there. Good thing you can't see all the skin flakes and other detritus that drops off human beings as they move around, including you, and including your own hair. Its just not noticeable if your hair is short.

Answer (score 0):

What worked well for for us is a **robotic vacuum cleaner**.
Its switched on every morning and when we return home it has finished its work and is back to its charging station. In the meantime it has picked up the mess two long-haired people, a toddler and some pet bunnies leave every day.

The downside is that they are still quite expensive, but as they free up quite a bit of time I consider them a good solution.

Comment: One big downside of robotic vacuum cleaners are **thresholds and storeys**. You can only use them on one floor and if not every room has high thresholds. A friend of mine has to place it into every room manually. So a perfect environment for robotic vacuum cleaners would be a flat apartment (wheelchair accessible).